# ¿Cómo puedo modificar al selector con un textarea y botón sin frameworks?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Quiero modificar el `innerHTML` (para eso uso el `textarea`) de un elemento en base a un selector que voy a buscar. ¿Cómo puedo modificar al selector con un `textarea` y botón sin frameworks?

```js
var frm = document.getElementById("frm");
frm.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  var selector = document.getElementById("input_selector").value;
  var inner = input_innerhtml.value;
  //lo que me falta es que el selector encontrado se modifique con lo que escribamos en el textarea sin usar frameworks
});
```

```html
<form id="frm">
  Selector de elemento CSS: <input type="text" id="input_selector"><br> 
  Valor = <textarea id="input_innerhtml"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Modificar">
</form>
```

Comment: Cómo que se modifique el select con el textarea? Te podrás explicar un poco mejor?

Comment: quiero modificar el innerHTML(para eso uso el textarea) de un elemento en base a un selector que voy a buscar

Comment: Hola Giovanni, por favor edita tu pregunta para añadir una descripción detallada del problema y las dificultades/problemas que quieres resolver. Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser bien recibidas por la comunidad. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: "en base a un selector que voy a buscar" explica eso mejor

Comment: var selector = document.getElementById("input_selector").value; // el usuario busca el selector en un input de tipo text

Comment: Quieres editar el innerHTML de un elemento que el usuario introduzca?

Comment: si y para eso uso el botón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, creo que he entendido que es lo que quieres hacer, como una especie de editor de código fuente?

He modificado el formulario, si haces un `submit` se borran los cambios, a ver si esto te sirve.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("boton");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  /// Esto te va a devolver el texto del campo 
  var selector = document.getElementById("input_selector").value;
  
  /// Ahora buscas el elemento
  var elemento = document.getElementById(selector);
  
  /// Conseguir el valor del textarea
  var nuevoValor = document.getElementById("input_innerhtml").value;
  
  /// Cambias el innerHTML de ese elemento
  elemento.innerHTML = nuevoValor;

});
```

```html
  Selector de elemento CSS: <input type="text" id="input_selector"><br>
  Valor = <textarea id="input_innerhtml"></textarea><br>
  
  
  <input type="button" id="boton" value="Modificar">
```

Comment: vale muchas gracias